# SQL How fill in last values of time series if date is missing

Tags: sql, vertica

In example: I have got the following table.

```
WITH
-- your input ....
input(t,grp,value) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-28 00:00:00','A',55
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-28 00:00:00','B',1.09
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-28 00:00:00','C',1.8
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-29 00:00:00','A',68
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-29 00:00:00','B',1.9
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-29 00:00:00','C',1.19
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01 00:00:00','A',10
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01 00:00:00','B',15
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01 00:00:00','C',0.88
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-02 00:00:00','A',22
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-02 00:00:00','B',15
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-02 00:00:00','C',13
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-03 00:00:00','A',66
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-03 00:00:00','B',88
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-03 00:00:00','C',99
)
```

As you can see between dates 2020-30-05 and 2020-31-05 are missing in this table. So it is necessary to fill these dates with 2020-29-05 information grouped by GROUP. Additionally today date is larger than in the data (06-03 vs 06-08) (so in current month these observations are missing.  As a result the final output should be like that :

```
date2                     Group    number
2020-28-05 00:00:00         A        55
2020-28-05 00:00:00         B        1.09
2020-28-05 00:00:00         C        1.8
2020-29-05 00:00:00         A        68
2020-29-05 00:00:00         B        1.9
2020-29-05 00:00:00         C        1.19
2020-30-05 00:00:00         A        68
2020-30-05 00:00:00         B        1.9
2020-30-05 00:00:00         C        1.19
2020-31-05 00:00:00         A        68
2020-31-05 00:00:00         B        1.9
2020-31-05 00:00:00         C        1.19
2020-01-06 00:00:00         A        10
2020-01-06 00:00:00         B        15
2020-01-06 00:00:00         C        0.88
2020-02-06 00:00:00         A        22
2020-02-06 00:00:00         B        15
2020-02-06 00:00:00         C        13
2020-03-06 00:00:00         A        66
2020-03-06 00:00:00         B        88
2020-03-06 00:00:00         C        99
And for periods 03-06 till 08-06 the same values

2020-08-06 00:00:00         A        66
2020-08-06 00:00:00         B        88
2020-08-06 00:00:00         C        99
```

The following code helps to find missing value in the dates, however those gaps are not filled up today dates. How to fix it?

```
SELECT ts AS t, grp, TS_FIRST_VALUE(value,'const') AS value
FROM input
TIMESERIES ts AS '1 DAY' OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY t)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called `INTERPOLATE` and not EXTRAPOLATE, and that's the challenge.

You'll need to add the last row per group, but with today's date instead of the actual/original date, to the input table.
Note the `padding` and `padded` common table expressions I'm using below. Vertica has the *analytic limit clause* that I'm using here: `LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY tmstmp DESC)`..

```
WITH
input(tmstmp,grp,nbr) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-28 00:00:00','A',55
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-28 00:00:00','B',1.09
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-28 00:00:00','C',1.8
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-29 00:00:00','A',68
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-29 00:00:00','B',1.9
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-29 00:00:00','C',1.19
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01 00:00:00','A',10
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01 00:00:00','B',15
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01 00:00:00','C',0.88
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-02 00:00:00','A',22
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-02 00:00:00','B',15
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-02 00:00:00','C',13
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-03 00:00:00','A',66
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-03 00:00:00','B',88
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-03 00:00:00','C',99
)
,
padding AS (
  SELECT
    CURRENT_DATE::timestamp
  , grp
  , nbr
  FROM input
  LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY tmstmp DESC)
)
,
padded AS (
  SELECT * FROM input
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM padding
)
SELECT
  ts AS tmstmp
, grp
, TS_FIRST_VALUE(nbr,'const') AS nbr
FROM padded
TIMESERIES ts AS '1 DAY' OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY tmstmp)
ORDER BY 1,2
;
-- out        tmstmp        | grp |  nbr  
-- out ---------------------+-----+-------
-- out  2020-05-28 00:00:00 | A   | 55.00
-- out  2020-05-28 00:00:00 | B   |  1.09
-- out  2020-05-28 00:00:00 | C   |  1.80
-- out  2020-05-29 00:00:00 | A   | 68.00
-- out  2020-05-29 00:00:00 | B   |  1.90
-- out  2020-05-29 00:00:00 | C   |  1.19
-- out  2020-05-30 00:00:00 | A   | 68.00
-- out  2020-05-30 00:00:00 | B   |  1.90
-- out  2020-05-30 00:00:00 | C   |  1.19
-- out  2020-05-31 00:00:00 | A   | 68.00
-- out  2020-05-31 00:00:00 | B   |  1.90
-- out  2020-05-31 00:00:00 | C   |  1.19
-- out  2020-06-01 00:00:00 | A   | 10.00
-- out  2020-06-01 00:00:00 | B   | 15.00
-- out  2020-06-01 00:00:00 | C   |  0.88
-- out  2020-06-02 00:00:00 | A   | 22.00
-- out  2020-06-02 00:00:00 | B   | 15.00
-- out  2020-06-02 00:00:00 | C   | 13.00
-- out  2020-06-03 00:00:00 | A   | 66.00
-- out  2020-06-03 00:00:00 | B   | 88.00
-- out  2020-06-03 00:00:00 | C   | 99.00
-- out  2020-06-04 00:00:00 | A   | 66.00
-- out  2020-06-04 00:00:00 | B   | 88.00
-- out  2020-06-04 00:00:00 | C   | 99.00
-- out  2020-06-05 00:00:00 | A   | 66.00
-- out  2020-06-05 00:00:00 | B   | 88.00
-- out  2020-06-05 00:00:00 | C   | 99.00
-- out  2020-06-06 00:00:00 | A   | 66.00
-- out  2020-06-06 00:00:00 | B   | 88.00
-- out  2020-06-06 00:00:00 | C   | 99.00
-- out  2020-06-07 00:00:00 | A   | 66.00
-- out  2020-06-07 00:00:00 | B   | 88.00
-- out  2020-06-07 00:00:00 | C   | 99.00
-- out  2020-06-08 00:00:00 | A   | 66.00
-- out  2020-06-08 00:00:00 | B   | 88.00
-- out  2020-06-08 00:00:00 | C   | 99.00
-- out  2020-06-09 00:00:00 | A   | 66.00
-- out  2020-06-09 00:00:00 | B   | 88.00
-- out  2020-06-09 00:00:00 | C   | 99.00
```